# Como puedo crear una fila/row temporal en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una fila temporal en mysql pero no lo puedo lograr, si puede lograr como crear una columna pero no se como hacer una fila. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Esta es la columna original

```
 _________________                 ______________      
|   Salario       |               |    AVERAGE   |
 _________________                |____________  |
|   200.000       |               |85585.714286  |
| ________________|               |______________|
```

^-------
Este es el resulatado original

Lo que yo intente

Este es el resultado querido --------------------------^

Lo que yo intente fue: `select "Average Salary", avg(salary) from EMP_DATA;`

Y crea esto

```
+----------------+--------------+
| Average Salary | avg(salary)  |
+----------------+--------------+
| Average Salary | 85585.714286 |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Pude hacer la columna pero eso no es lo que quiero hacer. Quiero que el valor de `avg(salary)` este debajo de Average Salary asi:

```
+----------------+
| Average Salary | 
+----------------+
| 85585.714286   | 
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente estás tratando de asignarle un alias a la columna?:

```
SELECT avg(salary) AS `Average Salary`
FROM EMP_DATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso no es una fila temporal, es un campo que incluyes en tu consulta, se pueden hacer tablas temporales, pero eso es de transact sql, el alias lo que realiza es dar un nombre mas entendible a la columna.